# Parsing Yaml in Python: Detect duplicated keys

Tags: python, regex, yaml, pyyaml

The `yaml` library in python is not able to detect duplicated keys. This is a bug that [has been reported years ago](http://pyyaml.org/ticket/128) and there is not a fix yet.

I would like to find a decent workaround to this problem. How plausible could be to create a `regex` that returns all the keys ? Then it would be quite easy to detect this problem.

Could any regex master suggest a regex that is able to extract all the keys to find duplicates ?

File example:

```
mykey1:
    subkey1: value1
    subkey2: value2
    subkey3:
      - value 3.1
      - value 3.2
mykey2:
    subkey1: this is not duplicated
    subkey5: value5
    subkey5: duplicated!
    subkey6:
       subkey6.1: value6.1
       subkey6.2: valye6.2
```

Comment: Their implementation sucks! I agree with you, they should have added the option in the constructor. Did you find a way to verify documents programmatically?

Comment: There are generally a couple of approaches to missing library features: either fix it or get a different library. Fixing it can range from a local patch to a full blown PR. If the library is generally useful and good, PR is the way to go

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [yamllint](http://yamllint.readthedocs.org/) command-line tool does what you
want:

```
sudo pip install yamllint
```

Specifically, it has a rule `key-duplicates` that detects repetitions and keys
over-writing one another:

```
$ yamllint test.yaml
test.yaml
  1:1       warning  missing document start "---"  (document-start)
  10:5      error    duplication of key "subkey5" in mapping  (key-duplicates)
```

(It has many other rules that you can enable/disable or tweak.)

Answer (score 11):

Over-riding on of the build in loaders is a more lightweight approach:

```
 import yaml
 # special loader with duplicate key checking
 class UniqueKeyLoader(yaml.SafeLoader):
     def construct_mapping(self, node, deep=False):
         mapping = []
         for key_node, value_node in node.value:
             key = self.construct_object(key_node, deep=deep)
             assert key not in mapping
             mapping.append(key)
         return super().construct_mapping(node, deep)
```

then:

```
 yaml_text = open(filename), 'r').read()
 data[f] = yaml.load(yaml_text, Loader=UniqueKeyLoader)
```

Comment: This is elegant and straightforward, unlike many recommendations that require importing another package.

Answer (score 1):

**ErichBSchulz** great effort. thanks for the fixed code.
here I did minor changes. Updating the file name with line and column.

```
class UniqueKeyLoader(yaml.SafeLoader):
    def construct_mapping(self, node, deep=False):
        mapping = set()
        for key_node, value_node in node.value:
            each_key = self.construct_object(key_node, deep=deep)
            if each_key in mapping:
                raise ValueError(f"Duplicate Key: {each_key!r} is found in YAML File.\n"
                                 f"Error File location: {key_node.end_mark}")
            mapping.add(each_key)
        return super().construct_mapping(node, deep)

with open(test_suite_full_path, 'r') as f:
    yaml_ret_dict = yaml.load(f, Loader=UniqueKeyLoader)
```

Comment: @LeiMao, good catch. But don't add meta information (like edited on 28.02.2024) in posts, unless there is a really good reason for it. Please, flag this comment as no longer needed, once you see it.